# In here maps while testing my api code and app code for places API I am getting 401 despite I have recently generated new API codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, here-api, here-maps-rest

In here maps while testing my api_id and app_code in jsfiddle for places API I am getting 401 unauthorised, despite I have recently generated new API codes.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    at: '41.8369,-87.684',
    app_id: '{demoappid}',
    app_code: '{demoappcode}'
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  error: function(a, b, c){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
  }
});
```

Comment: oh I am sorry I need to remove curly braces...Its working fine now...Alhamdulillah...

Answer (score 1):

Please Remove the { } in api I'd and api code and try